# drug and drop замена блока на javascript (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, объекты, drag-n-drop, draggable

Есть массив объектов, который сверстан как 6 картинок.(циклом v-for).
Так же сверстано по 6 серых блоков в двух колонках справа(простые div'ы).
Нужно перенести картинку со своего места и вставить в один из блоков справа,
При том что справа так же 2 массива: 1 - жанры, 2 - не являющиеся жанрами.
Нужно перенести картинку и вставить в определенный серенький блок, вместо этого серого блока появляется эта картинка и объект этой картинки пушится в соответствующий массив.

Не пойму как реализовать так чтобы картинка заменяла серый блок.. Может не через дивы рисовать серые блоки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно не **перемещать** блоки. Вам тем более **не нужно перемещать элементы из DOM**.

Вам нужно сделать компонент, который рендерит книгу или, если книги нет, пустой блок.

Далее, при заверении процесса Drag&Drop (подняли, перенесли, отпустили) из ячейки откуда перенесли книгу данные о книге удалять, а в тот компонент, куда перенесли - добавлять.

Для упрощения можно использовать какую-нибудь готовую библиотеку.

Например, первое, что попалось в поиске: https://github.com/cameronhimself/vue-drag-drop.